# Issue with stitching thousands of planar constructs together in Python

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a function that takes inputs X_inp and Y_inp that outputs a planar equation Z = a + bx + cy, where inputting X_inp and Y_inp for x and y will set Z equal to the plane tangent to the goal equation.

How can I take this function, call it several hundreds of thousands of times, and stitch the outputted planes together into the singular goal equation f(x, y)?

I have already tried using Polynomial Regression, Random Forests, and a GAN. All of these methods not suited for my problem in the end however. I believe Polynomial Regression might have some potential still.